# Look for a register without writing it exactly in C#

Tags: c#

Here's my code. The txtBuscar is the textbox where I'm writing the register I want to search. The table was created in Access, and has 3 Columns, Nombre (name), Dirección, (adress), and Telefono (phone number).

The Form has 3 radiobuttons, one related with each column. If I write a name in the textbox and I checked the radName, then I'll begin a search on all the registers, comparing it with what's written in the row Name.

My goal is to find one or 2 registers without writing the whole content, example:

If I write on the textbox "Ja", the DataGrid will show me the "James" and "Jacob" registers, with the rest of the rows.

But instead, I need to write the whole content in the textbox so the program can look for it.

```
        string nDato = txtBuscar.Text;
        OleDbConnection conexion = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Roberto\Documents\38_2.accdb");
        OleDbCommand instruccion = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Tabla1",conexion);
        OleDbDataReader lector;

        conexion.Open();

        lector = instruccion.ExecuteReader();

        while (lector.Read())
        {
            if (radName.Checked == true)
            {
                if (lector["Nombre"].ToString() == nDato)
                {
                    string[] nCad = new string[] { lector["Nombre"].ToString(), lector["Dirección"].ToString(), lector["Telefono"].ToString()};
                    dgvConsultas.Rows.Add(nCad);
                }

            }
            else if (radAdd.Checked == true)
            {
                if (lector["Dirección"].ToString() == nDato)
                {
                    string[] nCad = new string[] { lector["Nombre"].ToString(), lector["Dirección"].ToString(), lector["Telefono"].ToString() };
                    dgvConsultas.Rows.Add(nCad);
                }
            }
            else if (radPho.Checked == true)
            {
                if (lector["Telefono"].ToString() == nDato)
                {
                    string[] nCad = new string[] { lector["Nombre"].ToString(), lector["Dirección"].ToString(), lector["Telefono"].ToString() };
                    dgvConsultas.Rows.Add(nCad);
                }
            }
        }
        conexion.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I 'think' I understand what you are trying to do.  Access supports the LIKE qualifier with wild cards.

This might work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla1 WHERE Nombre LIKE 'Ja*'
```